# Is there a way to offset an edge? (extrude edge loop perpendicular to each edge)

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

I recently figured out how to do it with faces, but with edges, I can't seem to get it to work. I have a complex flat plane and i need to extend an edge loop. I tried setting to individual origins in combination with all possibilities for x,y,z axes in global and local, but it is still not extruding along the normals.

[image: Valid XHTML]

actual problem

[image: Valid XHTML]

simplified

Comment: exactly, since i am dealing with a plane-like surface

Comment: Is it like Inset edge?

Comment: yes, like offsetting an edge, thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: zeffii, thanks for pointing me in the right direction. the zmj100 pack has an addon that does an inset/offset of an outline (happy i saw it before it was deleted :). it is no longer the original one, but now it is called SIRE outline.

Comment: Your images are 404 errors now. In questions / answers here please use embedded tool to upload them. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ZMJ100 wrote an addon called **SIRE outline**. When installed it will appear in the left hand toolshelf in 3dview. It does offset (inset, outset).

[image]

https://vimeo.com/28147691 (demo video by tungee)

Over at BlenderArtists [ZMj100 went crazy (in a good way) writing mesh addons](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?179375-Addon-Edge-fillet-and-other-bmesh-tools-Update-Jan-11), one of the addons does exactly what you want. It's probably not polite to link someone elses collection directly here, although I would like to. but here is a direct link to the thread and the zip is in the thread. It's all GPL license.

Comment: it's on the first page of the [forum thread](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?179375-Addon-Edge-fillet-and-other-bmesh-tools-Update-Jan-11) you posted.

Answer (score 3):

I keep having to re-reference this. Seeming as the SIRE tools are not being developed (or perhaps called something else), here is an addon that I have recently discovered that works well: https://github.com/Bombaba/BlenderPythonScripts/blob/master/mesh_offset_edges.py

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for this addon - have been looking for a script that would do this for ages!

Comment: Not working in 2.79. After the file is downloaded and installed without error, there is no related entry in 3D > Edit Mode > Edges menu.