# How to add resolution to a mesh created from a curve

Tags: modeling, workflow, bezier-curves

I am creating an axe, I currently have this outline that I traced from a background image. I have converted it to a mesh from a Bezier curve using <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>, but now I want to give it some depth.

How can I add resolution to the large NGON face? I need resolution so that I can chamfer the edges towards the sharp points on each side.

Here is what my mesh looks like.

[image: Mesh converted from Bezier curve.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to go about this would be to make use of an addon called [*SIRE outline*](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?179375-Addon-Edge-fillet-and-other-bmesh-tools-Update-Jan-11). Also see [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/1092/12).

Once you have installed it. It should appear in the *Toolshelf*, <kbd>T</kbd>. What you should be after early is supporting geometry with good edgeflow.

[image]

Use the *Inset* feature of the addon and offset your outline to the desired amount.

[image]

After that, it's just a matter of filling in the even faces and for the rest, you have the supporting geometry near the curved edges so a ngon should suffice.

[image]

After that, it is as simple as extruding the model, giving it some depth and chamfering the edges. If you should also need to smooth the model, to keep it sharp simply add edgeloops to the edges or make use of the crease tool.

Comment: iKIsR great plugin can u share the link plz to download that addon SIRE Outline

Comment: @atek I don't know if this is still working but you can poke around the BA thread to see if there are any download links. See https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?179375-Addon-Edge-fillet.-%2528Two-new-addons-post-65-and-post-72-%2529/page4

Comment: is there any alternate to that addon

Comment: @atek not that I know of, this was 3 years ago.

Comment: I mean is there any other alternate or similar addon with that feature as i want to offset the edge out side and inside