# Add walls to 2D floor plan

Tags: geometry, extrude

I have the blueprint of a room in my flat as a planar 2D vertex, example:

[image]

I want to add walls to it that are going into the Z direction. I have tried several modifiers and searched with Google, but i have not come up with a fast and easy way to do it. Currently my method is to create a new, second vertex and measure all edge lengths, then recreate the shape and extrude it into the Z direction. There surely must be a better way, maybe with a modifier -- but  how?

Comment: u can go with the addon called archipack & archimesh or solidify modifier or with intersect

Comment: There is paid add on available to speed up wall creation. It's called Quick Wall

Answer (score 1):

Inset the face you have with <kbd>I</kbd>, invert the selection (since the area which was inset will remain selected) with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and then extrude.

[image]

Note that depending on the case you might need to change topology in the end to convert Ngons to something more appropriate. Though if no subdividing with modifiers like Subsurf is used then it won't be that necessary.

Comment: Actually that was one of the first things I tried. The downside is that you have to construct the geometry to a larger scale because inset will shrink the faces. That is a huge downside if you have exact measurements. Additionally, the geometry is not that great because of the diagonals at the edges (that wouldn't be a gamechanger for my use case, tho).

Comment: @hochl the only way to create geometry of the walls connected to the floor is to extrude them somehow. I don't have any idea regarding larger scale, if you have any trouble with some more complex case then provide it in the question. There is Offset Edges addon for more precise extruding/offsetting them, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/is-there-a-way-to-offset-an-edge-extrude-edge-loop-perpendicular-to-each-edge