# How to extrude edges outward based on multiple axes?

Tags: modeling, edges, extrude

I want to extrude these edges outward so that they are all the same length from their origin edge. Does anyone know how I could do this without doing each edge individually?
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1088/is-there-a-way-to-offset-an-edge-extrude-edge-loop-perpendicular-to-each-edge/

Answer (score 0):

Once you've extrude, press <kbd>enter</kbd>, then try <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> (*Shrink/Flatten*). You can play with some parameters on the bottom of the *Tools* panel (on the left of your 3D View, displayed with <kbd>T</kbd>).